# How to design a proper functional database, respecting the normalization rules, for a company that provides various types of services?

Tags: database, t-sql

I am not a database specialist. So far, I have only been working on a less complex databases.
I am making asp.net mvc application, for a company that provides various services. The main categories of services are: Digital printing, Graphic design, Web design, Photography. The problem arises when determining the price. The price of digital printing depends on whether it is one-sided or double-sided, whether it is black and white or in color, it depends on the paper whose price changes depending on the format, also depends on the quantity.

  Example:
- Paper: Mondy 80g on A4 format, price 0,008 euro per piece
- Paper: Mondy 80g on A3 format, price 0,02 euro per piece
  etc...
- Printing: one-sided black and white on A4 format, quantity from 1-20, price 0,08 euro per piece
- Printing: one-sided black and white on A4 format, quantity from 21-100, price 0,04 euro per piece
  etc...

So if I decide to print 52 pages one-sided black and white, on Mondy 80g papper on A4 format, the final price would be 2,5 euros...(52x0,008)+(52x0,04)
On the other hand, graphic design is priced by hour...
Here is a diagram of what I have done so far

[image: diagram]

Of course it is not over. I will later add customer table, orders etc...
In the quantity table, I left minValue as the Null field, because of the graphic design etc, because they are charged per hour, so I can create the quantity unit per hour, and I put the maximum number of hours for, say, the creation of a logo
This is T-Sql of the database

```
USE [master]
GO

CREATE DATABASE [Infinity]
GO

USE [Infinity]
GO

CREATE SCHEMA [Services]
GO

CREATE SCHEMA [Materials]
GO

CREATE SCHEMA [Sales]
GO

CREATE TABLE [Services].[Category]
(
    CategoryId int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    CategoryName nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    CategoryDescription nvarchar(300) NULL
);

CREATE TABLE [Materials].[Format]
(
    FormatId int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    FormatName nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    FormatHeight nvarchar(20) NOT NULL,
    FormatWidth nvarchar(20) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE [Materials].[Paper]
(
    PaperId int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    PaperName nvarchar(50) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE [Materials].[Quantity]
(
    QuantityId int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    QuantityName nvarchar(30) NOT NULL,
    QuantityUnit nvarchar(30) NOT NULL,
    QuantityMinValue int NULL,
    QuantityMaxValue int NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE [Services].[Service]
(
    ServiceId int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    ServiceName nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    ServiceDescription nvarchar(300) NULL,
    CategoryId int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [Services].[Category] 
    (CategoryId) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE [Sales].[ServicePrice]
(
    ServicePriceId int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    ServiceId int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [Services].[Service](ServiceId) 
    NOT NULL,
    QuantityId int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [Materials].[Quantity] 
    (QuantityId) NOT NULL,
    FormatId int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [Materials].[Format](FormatId) 
    NULL,
    PaperId int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [Materials].[Paper](PaperId) NULL,
    Price decimal(12,2) NOT NULL
);
```

I am interested in whether this is well designed or there is a better way to do it? Any suggestions?

Comment: Is there a good reason for using multiple schemas? Also, I think that this is a bit too broad for stackoverflow. You need a professional advice from someone that have access to all the different requirements. I would consider paying a consultant for a few hours of work for this if I was in your place.

Comment: You want to think about the register tape when thinking about how to price things and less on the features of the things you'll sell. For example, unless there's a compelling reason to keep FormatHeight and FormatWidth (that is...using the height and width as components of a price calculation), I wouldn't do it. My inclination is to reduce the things that are sold to item price * quantity. Therefore a service isn't actually different than a digital print. A digital print on Mondy 80g A4 is a priced thing...and not necessarily a composition of individually priced sub features.

Comment: It's only gonna get worse when you start pricing discounts and promotions. Thus...I agree with @ZoharPeled, you need a couple of hours of a consultant to help with the design. Multiple schemas...and overly complex pricing stuff (so far). This stuff is pretty boilerplate...and you'd be better off following a template. The microsoft sample applications are pretty robust and would be good starting points...and cover a lot of edge cases that you're going to run into.

Comment: I meant to say a "Mondy 80g A4 digital 1 sided B/W print" is a single priced thing...IMHO.

Comment: Thank you both for advice. There is no special reason for using multi-schemes. I use them from my personal needs to organize things more easily. Generally, printing 1 side B/W A4 on Mondy 80g is actually one product, so the ServicePrice table is unnecessary.